# How to keep the number fraction format in Rstudio while performing simple operations?

Tags: rstudio, grouping, categories

I have one column, with EU countries, what I need is to create three groups of countries inside this columns:
1st group: All Europe (that will contain all European Countries)
2nd group: Central Europe(that will contain only Central EU countries)
3rd group: Others(European NON central)

how can I do that?
thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please add a sample of your data so that we may assists better?

Comment: I am using this country column in Shiny sidebar, in filtering by country, with a SelectInput() ... when i scroll this filter, I see each name of a country as an option to be choosen, what I need is to make it easier for users, instead of choosing multiple countries - to have another 3 options(All europe, Central, nonCentral), in the same scroll down menu

Comment: @Maylo Thank you for fast reply, my problem is that my code is very huge, and also for a company which cannot be shared due to privacy policy, and I am new to stack overflow, and donno still how to write a reproducible example to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `selectizeInput` could help:

```
selectizeInput('countries', 'Countries', choices = list(
      'All Europe' = c('country1','country2'),
      'Central Europe' = c('country1','country2'),
      Others = c('country1','country2')
    ), multiple = TRUE)
```

Although the user will still have to manually select each country. If you could find a way to create sample code (without providing your company's data, maybe creating a similar dummy table?) I could provide a more to the point solution.

Comment: Countries
_________
country 1
country 2
country 3
country 4
country 5
country 6
country 7
country 8
country 9
country 10
country 11
country 12

 > selectInput(inputId = "country", label = "Country", choices 
 > =unique(c(MYDATA$Countries)), selected = "country 1", selectize = TRUE,
 > multiple = F),

Comment: selectInput(inputId = "country", label = "Country", choices > =unique(c(MYDATA$Countries)), selected = "country 1", selectize = TRUE, > multiple = F)

Comment: can i have ur email?